# Navbar within columns, Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am wondering if it is necessary to put navbar content into the container/container-fluid, for example:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid"> etc...
```

If that is a must then there is no proper way to place navbar within some column elements(col-*) since containers can not be nested.
Can anyone confirm this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Containers *can* be nested, it's just not recommended. But if the layout you're going for *requires* putting the navbar within some .cols, just try it! Then come back asking for help if it's not working the way you want...

Comment: I have tried it and it does not look good on ipad devices, thats why I am asking. Documentation clearly says that containers are not nestable , it does not say that it is not recommended. And you rate my question as bad...

Comment: chill dude. I didn't rate your question at all. and 'not nestable' doesn't mean you can't try, just like 'not edible'. you CAN eat rocks, even though they're not edible.

Comment: if you want to know why you're question was downvoted, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask